# Regex for finding jpg

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, jpeg

I have a problem when I try to get (`https://XXXXX.jpg`)

I'm using this format: (`https://.*.jpg`) However it doesn't find what I want.

It returns, for example, (`https://XXXXX.jpg <## Heading ##div> bla bla bla </div> bla bla https://XYZ .jpg`)

Startswith `https`, endswith `jpg`.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure those are supposed to be backslashes?

Comment: the regex you are using seems to be find, can you upload the input string.        \\ -> // ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the non-greedy `?` character to match what you want.

So your final regex will be `https:\\\\.*?\.jpg`

See this [regex101 link](http://regex101.com/r/fZ0fD9) for further explanation.

Btw, as @Jerry mentioned in the comments, are you sure those are supposed to be backslashes and not frontslashes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(https.+\.jpg)\s
```

For:

```
(https:\\XXXXX.jpg <\div> bla bla bla <\div> bla bla https:\\XYZ .jpg)
```

It will match:

```
https:\\XXXXX.jpg
```

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/bR5lL5)

Answer (score 0):

Split on the whole string, then use a loop to iterate the splitted items, each time comparing with `startswith("http"` and `endswith(".jpg")`